# I Have a Question on Borel Sets.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Consider any topological space $(X, \tau)$ and suppose that $\mathbb{K} \subset \tau$ is a basis for the topology $\tau$. Suppose further that $\mathbb{K} $ is a countable basis. Is it true that the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb{K}$, $\sigma(\mathbb{K})$, equals the intersection of sigma algebras that contain $\mathbb{K}$?

By definition, $\sigma(\tau)$ is the sigma algebra generated by $\tau$, which is the smallest sigma algebra containing $\tau$ in the sense of being a subset of all such sigma algebras.

In the question, I think this is true since $\mathbb{K} \subseteq \tau$ this implies that  $\mathbb{K} \subseteq \sigma(\tau)$. Therefore, this implies that  $ \sigma(\mathbb{K}) \subseteq \sigma(\tau)$.

I am not sure what to say next. I want to show that $\sigma(\tau) \subseteq \sigma(\mathbb{K})$. Am I on the right track? Can you only give out hints please? Thank you very much!

Comment: The Borel sets of $\Bbb K$? You mean, I think, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by  $\Bbb K$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof so far is correct.

For the other direction, since $\mathbb{K}$ is a basis for the topology every open set $O\in\tau$ is a union of open sets from $\mathbb{K}$, and since $\mathbb{K}$ is countable $O$ is necessarily a countable union of open sets from $\mathbb{K}$. This shows that $O$ is in the sigma algebra generated by $\mathbb{K}$, so $\tau\subseteq\sigma(\mathbb{K})$ and hence by minimality $\sigma(\tau)\subseteq\sigma(\mathbb{K})$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\Bbb K$ contains $\tau$ (as all open sets are (countable) unions of base elements. This holds already in hereditarily Lindelöf general spaces and certainly in second countable ones.

So $\tau \subseteq \sigma(\Bbb K)$ and so by minimality $\sigma(\tau) \subseteq \sigma(\Bbb K)$.